# How to convert an NSString to an NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSString`, that when I `NSLog`, it looks like this:

```
(
    Music,
    Music,
    "Ao Dai Fashion Show"
)
```

I would like to convert this to an NSArray, where array[0] = Music, array[1] = Music, and array[2] = Ao Dai Fashion Show.

I have tried to first remove the () using:

```
NSString *jsonString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"()" withString:@""];
```

However, I receive an `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

This is the original array:

```
NSArray *oriArray = [dictionary objectForKey:someKey];
```

`NSLog`:

```
(
        {
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = Music;
        "english_performer" = "DJ Happee From Channel 93.3";
        "start_time" = "20:00";
    },
        {
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = Music;
        "english_performer" = "Adam Cease";
        "start_time" = "20:00";
    },
        {
        "end_time" = "21:00";
        "english_event" = "Ao Dai Fashion Show";
        "english_performer" = "";
        "start_time" = "20:00";
    }
)
```

Here is the code to get the new `NSArray` containing contents `Music, Music, "Ao Dai Fashion"`:

```
NSArray *newArry = [oriArray valueForKey:@"english_event"];
```

However, the `newArry` is giving me an error when I try to access its index.

Comment: please show the real error you got. you have [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: the error is `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: __Full__ error message please. And I really mean the error _before_ you trying to convert that "string" to array. (it is not NSString as others already point out)

Comment: Also, why is the word Music isn't between quotes? It doesn't seem like valid json. And Bryan is right, you should include the entire error message.

Comment: At you need to understand " (
    Music,
    Music,
    "Ao Dai Fashion Show"
) :  this is an array .

Comment: Why are you using `valueForKey:` for key on your array? I know `NSArray` has this method but your key isn't `english_event`. You need to get the object at the index which is returning a dictionary which you then want to use the key `english_event` on. For example : `[[oriArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"englist_event"];` and by the looks of you (What I can only think is a json response) when you do this call it will return a string not an array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you're logging is actually an `NSString`. Please check its type because it seems like it's already an instance of `NSArray`. Therefore you should already be able to do what you want.

Comment: it's weird because it really is an NSString, but looks like an NSArray array. However, when I changed its type to NSArray, there was no error :|

Comment: That's probably because it's an `NSArray` :) If it were a `NSString`, then you wouldn't have gotten that error. Also, the output of your `NSLog` call is exactly how `NSLog` prints out an `NSArray`. An array is written between `[ ]` characters when formatting in JSON, not between `( )`, so it's not a json string.

Comment: Even though its an NSArray, how can I convert this NSArray to a, I guess, standard array? Because when I try to access `array[0]`, or even do `[array count]`, the app crashes with the same type of error.

Comment: `NSArray` is already a regular array. If you still get errors, that means something else is going on, check the value of the class property of your object to make sure of its actual type. Can you show the code you used to get the object that you had logged in your quesion?

Answer (score 1):

-(void)parse:(NSDictionary*)dictionary{

```
NSArray *oriArray = [dictionary objectForKey:someKey];
NSMutableArray *arrray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dic in oriArray)
{
    [arrray addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"english_event"]];

}
```

}

use this it may help you....

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I din't have the reputation to comment, I just thought of asking this, did you try- 
    NSArray *myArray = [stringOi componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
(*where stringOi is your str)
I tried with the following sample and this works, please do try yours.

NSString *stringOi=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(
    Music,
    Music,
    "Ao Dai Fashion Show"
)"];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringOi);

```
NSString *jsonString = [stringOi stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];

NSString *jsonStringFinal = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonStringFinal);

NSArray *myArray = [jsonStringFinal componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *myArray1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@",myArray1);
NSArray *myArray2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@",myArray2);
NSArray *myArray3 = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"%@",myArray3);
```

Alternatively instead of oriArray you can get the values in a dictionary dict and then,

NSArray *myArray1 = [dict objectForKey:@"english_event"];
 NSString *Music= [myArray1 objectAtIndex:0];

Hope for the best..!

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. `NSArray *myArray = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"Valid Key"]` does not mean that `myArray` is actually an Array. It just means it's a pointer to an object that you've cast as an `NSArray`.
2. You can convert any `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` to a string using `[myDictionaryOrArray description]`.

If you don't care about taking extra steps and know that when you log out the array you get what you want/are expecting, then you can definitely get your string into an array. For example:

```
NSString *myString = [@[Music, Music, "Ao Dai Fashion Show"] description];
NSMutableArray *stringAsArray =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
// this loop removes the white space before and after each word in the array
for (int i = 0; i < stringAsArray.count; i++) {
    stringAsArray[i] = [stringAsArray[i] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

If you need more specific code for the longer sample you gave, I'll be happy to update my answer.

Comment: I tried this code: `NSString *myString = [@[@"Music", @"Music", @"Ao Dai Fashion Show"] description];` and it produces the same result as the `NSString` output from my question. However, after I `NSLog` the `stringAsArray`, I get this output: `(
    "(\n    Music",
    Music,
    "\"Ao Dai Fashion Show\"\n)"
)` ...This is AFTER trimming

Comment: When you log the `stringAsArray` is that before or after trimming the white space and new line characters from each string?

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    Music,
    Music,
    "Ao Dai Fashion Show"
)
```

**this is an array not a string**.

This array holds three strings in each indexes , Music, Music, Ao Dai Fashion Show